# how to repeat this method 5 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a svg rect array:

```
   var rects[]; 
   function drawRect() {
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
     var rect = document.createElementNS(NS, 'rect'); 
     rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "srect"+i); 
     rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x); 
     rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
     rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '80');
     rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '80');
     rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#000000');
     rects.push(rect); 
     document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(rects[i]);  
     x+=80;
  }
```

...skip...

```
 function actionRect() { 
 var j=0;
 //up
 $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000); 
 $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000, function() { 
  //down
  $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000); 
  $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
   j=j+1; //j=1
   //up
   $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000); 
   $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000, function() {
     //down
     $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000); 
     $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
     j=j+1; //j=2
     //up
     $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000); 
     $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000, function() {
       //down
       $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000); 
       $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
         j=j+1; //j=3
         //up
         $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000); 
         $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000, function() {
           //down
           $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000); 
           $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
             j=j+1; //j=4
             //up
             $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000); 
             $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '50px'}, 1000, function() {
             //down
             $('#'+rects[j].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000); 
             $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
             });
            });
           });
          });
         });
        });
       });
      });
     });
    });
  }
```

This method is move to svg rects in array.
Although code is little dirty, that's only way to move success two rects at same time when i tried it dozens of times...
But it doesn't work when i add this code.

```
function actionRect() { 
 for(var k=0; k<5; k++) {
  var j=0;
  //up
  ...same way...
```

how can i repeat this method 5 times?

Comment: Post a failing jsfiddle.net

Comment: +1 to Oleander — @kanok, you need to show some context for how this is used.  Similarly, on the current answers here you say "I tried this ... it doesn't work", but both answers show concepts, not complete programs. Create a fiddle for each showing ***how*** you tried the answer, _in context_. Simply saying "it doesn't work" tells us nothing.

Comment: ye i miss important thing. ok i create fiddle now

Answer (score 0):

call it recursive:

```
function actionRect(repeat, counter){
   counter = counter || 0;
   if(repeat === counter){
      return;
   }

  ....your code
  ....recall the function in the last callback
  $('#'+rects[j+1].id).animate({y: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
     actionRect(repeat, counter++)
  });

}
actionRect(5)
```

Comment: what mean counter = counter || 0;? animate can only use function(){ what do i do?

Comment: you define "repeat" when you call the function, actionRect(5), counter = counter || 0 means if the counter is not set it becomes 0

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a simple callback Hell. Remember that repeating code isn't a good practice in any programming languages.

```
var j = 0; ///counter
var up = function() {
   console.log("foo");
};
var down = function() {
   console.log("bar");
};
function actionRect(callback1, callback2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    callback1();
    callback2();
    j++; //counter
    console.log("counter is at " + j);
  }
}
actionRect(up, down);
```

Try this, and see how the callback function is working.

Comment: i tried this... but i see this error [Uncaught TypeError: callback1 is not a function]. how can i fix it? should i create callback1()? and i can't move two rects at same time when if i use this code.

Comment: actionRect has two arguments: callback1 and callback 2. We know for a fact that callback1 and callback2 are function. 
actionRect(up, down); //when this executes, it looks like this
function actionRect(up, down) {
  for lopp{
    up();
    down();
  }
}